# Does a roommate count as being married for Grandpa's Evaluation?

Tags: stardew-valley

I'm talking about

> Inviting Krobus to live with you

Being married with a fully upgraded house is worth 1 point in Grandpa's evaluation. Does this roommate count in the same way?

Comment: Calling that character a "roommate" was probably just to avoid the obvious implication should they be called "married" (i.e. that the farmer and character were doing adult stuff to one another) along with all the IRL drama it might or might not cause. As far as the game is concerned, it is the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [a comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/StardewValley/comments/e4pw86/question_regarding_krobus_14_spoilers/) on Reddit, it is enough to have a roommate instead of being married.

> When I put my housemate-Krobus save file through Stardew Checkup, it said it does.